# Color line numbers part pitch black regardless of color scheme?

Tags: command-line, colorscheme

I have tried this:

```
:highlight LineNr ctermbg=black
```

but the problem is that apparently the color scheme I am using has changed the definition of "black", so instead of being black the gutter is now some blue color.

Comment: Actually it might be terminal program that changed that. Check terminal settings, maybe color palette has other color in place of what should be `black`

Comment: @grodzik yes that is true.

Comment: So could you rephrase title and question to specify `color scheme` of what (Vim/Terminal/...) are you referring to?

Comment: @theonlygusti instead of creating duplicate questions you can use the "edit" button to add more details to your question.